# Ubuntu upgrade issue - problem with partitioning boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade, uefi

I have a dual boot laptop system that has been running windows and Ubuntu 14 LTS. I just had my Motherboard, LCD screen, and LCD cable replaced on my laptop and now I can't get Ubuntu to load. Grub loads just fine but when I select Ubuntu I get the Ubuntu logo boot screen. Then I get a black screen that never goes anywhere. But I can select Windows and have it boot properly. After reading about fixes and trying them it seems I am left with trying to reinstall or upgrade using a Ubuntu live usb. When I attempt to upgrade I get an error message:

"The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as an "EFI boot partition" and should be at least 35 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot. If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error, boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be possible to install the boot loader to a partition."

I am not sure how to fix this problem. I have included a screen shot of both Gparted and the Installation type page. If any more information is needed to solve this problem please let me know. Thank you.

[image: gparted]

[image: installation]

Comment: It sounds very much like the technician who did the repairs replaced your Windows boot loader, eliminating grub and with it your ability to boot Ubuntu. See this for a better solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: Grub loads just fine but when I select Ubuntu I get the Ubuntu logo boot screen. Then I get a black screen that never goes anywhere. But I can select Windows and have it boot properly.

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Have you reviewed http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: The repair place probably didn't set the new motherboard's BIOS to the right setting. Enter your BIOS setup by holding down the appropriate function key, then check your setting **legacy/compatible/UEFI** and change it to the other value, and see if BOTH Ubuntu AND Windows will boot properly. Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: your Linux swap partition is way too big. Cheers, Al

Comment: Heynnema, I checked the BIOS setting again after you commented and for some reason the BIOS setting was on legacy not UEFI. I don't know when it changed because the technician that did the repair had to switch this setting to UEFI to get windows to boot after replacing the bad MoBo and screen. Thanks for the suggestion. Everything seems to be running just fine now.